# SQL Server 2005 most recent entry last month

Tags: sql-server-2005

My SQL Server Express 2005 table has `itemId,ItemName,price,ItemCount,date` columns with several rows entered every month.

I need to retrieve one single row for each most recent `itemId,ItemName,price,ItemCount,date` entered last month

Thank you a lot
Alberto

Comment: *most recent* by what? The `date` ?? *for each most recent* ... again: for each by what?? For each `itemId` ???

Comment: An example of data could explain a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY` clause.

Something like (not tested):

```
;WITH a AS (
SELECT
  itemId,ItemName,price,ItemCount,date
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemId,ItemName,price,ItemCount ORDER BY date DESC) AS num
FROM 
 table
WHERE
 date >= @begin_on_current_month
) 
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  a
WHERE
  a.num = 1
```

This should return last entry for each unique `itemId,ItemName,price,ItemCount` added after
`@begin_on_current_month`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work

SELECT     itemCode, ItemName, rate, found, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemCode
ORDER BY date DESC) AS num
FROM         StockCheck AS a
WHERE     date < '2012/01/01'
                          SELECT     a.*
                           FROM         a
                           WHERE     a.num = 1
                           ORDER BY itemcode

**The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.**

6173    ALUMINIUM FOIL 18" X 25'    77.0000 5.00    21/12/2011 00:00:00 1

6173    ALUMINIUM FOIL 18" X 25'    86.9159 9.00    15/12/2011 00:00:00 2

6173    ALUMINIUM FOIL 18" X 25'    70.0000 69.00   10/12/2011 00:00:00 3

6173    ALUMINIUM FOIL 18" X 25'    86.9159 9.00    01/12/2011 00:00:00 4